# Discord.js send a webhook

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Hi I have been experimenting with webhooks and I'm wondering how do you send a normal message(not embeded) through a webhook with a custom avatar and name

````
        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || client.users.cache.get(args[0]);
        let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if(!announcement) return message.channel.send(`lol say something`)

        const wc = new WebhookClient('id', 'token')
        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("").setColor('GREEN').setTimestamp().setDescription(announcement)
    wc.send({
        username : user.username,
        avatarURL : user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic : true }),
        embeds : [embed]
    })
    
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to send Discord webhooks you need to make a POST API request to the webhook url.

For that you can basically use any module you want however in this example I'll use `node-fetch`. Simply install it in your console

```
npm install node-fetch
```

and then require it where you need to use it

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
```

Now that we have what we need to make it work lets create the API request.

For that we start with the `params` variable. Here you set all the things that make the webhook look like you want it to look. *Note: I also included how to send embeds just in case. If you want to see all options check [here](https://gist.github.com/Birdie0/78ee79402a4301b1faf412ab5f1cdcf9).*

```
var params = {
    username: "Your name",
    avatar_url: "",
    content: "Some message you want to send",
    embeds: [
        {
            "title": "Some title",
            "color": 15258703,
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "",
            },
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "Your fields here",
                    "value": "Whatever you wish to send",
                    "inline": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now that we have the params we can create the actual POST request. For that you simply call the `fetch` function and provide the webhook url.

First you specify the method you want to use. By default the method is `GET`. Next make sure to set the headers to `'Content-type': 'application/json'`, otherwise you'll get an error. Lastly include the `params` from earlier in the body. We use `JSON.stringify()` here to make it work.

```
fetch('URL', {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(params)
}).then(res => {
    console.log(res);
})
```

At the end you have the option to catch any errors you might receive.