# Message Specific PFP. (like TupperBox)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am looking to send a message that has a different profile picture than the bot. Basically, like Tupper Bot does. I can't seem to figure out how to do it anywhere, I've read the documentation and searched around.

Comment: You might be able to use a webhook but it depends on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Thank you! Webhooks were exactly what I needed!

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca, you should put an answer into answers area. Then this question can be answered and give you the credit. ^w^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a webhook to do what you describe. If you already have a webhook link see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180201/discord-js-send-a-webhook/66180824#66180824) on how to use it. This works from external programs too.

If you don't, you can create a webhook with your bot and then send messages to it. In this example we will create a simple webhook and send a message to it.

First we should check if the channel already has a webhook. That way you don't create a new one everytime you use the command. You do that with the `fetchWebhooks()` function which returns a collection if there is a webhook present. If that is the case we will get the first webhook in the collection and use that. *Note: if you have more then one webhook you can of course add additional checks after the initial one.*

If there are no webhooks present, we create a new one with `createWebhook()`. You can pass [additional options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Webhook) after the name.

```
let webhook;
let webhookCollection = await message.channel.fetchWebhooks();
if (webhookCollection.first()) {
    webhook = webhookCollection.first();
} else {
    webhook = await message.channel.createWebhook("new webhook", {
        avatar: "https://i.imgur.com/tX5nlQ3.jpeg"
    });
}
```

*Note: in this example we use the channel the message came from but you can use any channel you want*

Technically we can now send messages already.

```
webhook.send("this is a test");
```

What you can also do is create a [`webhookClient`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient). Thats a little like the discord client you create when you start your bot. It takes the webhook ID and token as well as [additional options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) you can set for clients.

```
const hookclient = new Discord.WebhookClient(webhook.id, webhook.token);
```

This lets you use a few additional methods like `setInterval`.

```
hookclient.setInterval(() => {
    hookclient.send("This is a timer test");
}, 1000)
```

This lets you use the webhook without creating or fetching one first.